# django admin with mongodb

Tags: django, mongodb

I'm currently struggling with django admin and mongodb, I found some solutions about combining django admin and mongodb, but none of them is perfectly integrated with django admin. What I need is that I can do CRUD to mongodb tables in admin site like I use MySQL.

1. mongonaut : besides mapping to mongodb tables, mongonaut has permissions to do CRUD, but I don't know how to integreted mongonaut into django admin index page, mongonaut has its own page and css style to do CRUD.
2. mongoadmin : lack of permissions management is why I skipped it.

I am new to django，could anyone tell me what is your solution to integrated django admin and mongodb, thanks a lot !

Comment: Do you really need to use mongodb for the admin interface? The admin models do not map well onto a mongo database, this is why mongonaut is intended as a drop in replacement for the admin interface. Could you use this instead? Or alternatively connect to an sql database for the admin models and a mongo one for the rest of your site?

Comment: I wanted to switch to MySQL，but because of some dependences, I have to use MongoDB  :)